# Mongodb native driver timeout production values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There are timeout params for connecting to db: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#connection-configuration

What are the commonly used/recomended values for `connectTimeoutMS` and `socketTimeoutMS` in production, if I get it right by default there is no timeout set, is it really worth to set them in production?

Comment: It would really depend upon your network setup I believe.

Comment: You are referencing a really old driver. The new driver has default timeout values: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html

Comment: @nijm thanks, didn't noticed

Answer (score 0):

Suitable values for production depend on your setup and requirements, this cannot be generalised. However since version 2 of the driver there are default timeout values:

```
connectTimeoutMS: 30000
socketTimeoutMS: 360000
```

Note that version 1 of the MongoDB driver for node.js is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks, do I understand correctly that connectTimeout is for setting up connecting and socketTimeout for making/completing db requests?

Comment: See, a more detailed post on what these values mean and how these might affect your setup here: https://scalegrid.io/blog/understanding-mongodb-client-timeout-options/. But in short, yes